# Rendering videos in an SDL2 application

Tags: c++, video, sdl-2

I've been looking for a way to play videos at some point in my application, I was thinking of ways to incorporate them into a texture or just plain render them but I'm literally stumped here, any suggestion?
I'm not in a position to choose, but I'd really appreciate sample codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with OpenGL for example:
[play AVI files](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/playing_avi_files_in_opengl/23001/)

I'd include the source of the link but since it's a full fledged tutorial that would be too long.

[Different approach](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/216358/an-avi-media-player-dev-c)

Another option would be to just have the media player start.
Most players have start parameters that you can use.

for example:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hRet = ShellExecuteA(
                HWND_DESKTOP,                               // Parent
                "open",                                     // Operation
                "C:\\yourMovieDirectory\\yourMovie.avi",    // Path to file
                NULL,                                       // Parameters
                NULL,                                       // Default dir.
                SW_SHOW);                                   // Opening option

    if( (LONG)hRet <= 32 )
    {
        MessageBox( HWND_DESKTOP , "Error detected while attempting to start the movie!") , "Error" , MB_OK );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

You need the shell32.lib for the [ShellExecute() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

HINSTANCE is a handle to an instance.
[C++ Windows Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I really appreciated this, especially the sample code.... thing is, I can't seem to implement it, could you refer me to the origin of this code? or did I miss some pre-requisites? I tried to type HINSTANCE into my project and it didn't really recognize it. Sorry, but it's my first encounter for this one.

Comment: updated. Sorry I was assuming you're using windows. If it's not the case let me know.

Comment: I'm actually using windows 8... Never mind, I didn't know that you had to include windows.h. Let me try this again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I finally got it.